# Is there a Cart/Catalog app out there that isnt a full site?

Tags: php, python, ruby, e-commerce

Every solution i come across seems to be a complete store with far too many options and too much functionality.

I can write my own cart to get the minimal functionality i need out of the frontend, im just trying to cut out the time writing a complex backend. What im really looking for is something that offers the backend functionality for a product catalog, order management, etc. while providing a smooth and consistent API to access the data for my completely custom frontend application.

The frontend will be in PHP so the API would have to be native PHP or some kind of web service interface i can create my own php models around. It would need to run on a LAMP stack and would preferably be written in PHP, Python, or Ruby just in case i need to customize the backend (she curently has ZenCart and **hates** it - says its far too complicated and sophisticated for her needs).

Does such a thing exist? Or what would be the next best thing?

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about [Google Base](http://code.google.com/apis/base/) solution (Ok, you can't install on your LAMP stack)?
It offers [products](http://code.google.com/apis/base/starting-out.html#products) management and has [PHP Api](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html) distribuited as part of Zend.

Comment: I havent looked at this yet (THANKS for the info) but not being able to install it is fine SaaS would be more than appropriate in this instance.

Comment: Just found BigCommerce (http://www.bigcommerce.com) as well,  for anyone else open to a SaaS solution.

Comment: Cool solution, i thought you was searching for a backend solution.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer this but [Moltin](https://molt.in) offers a backend solution accessible via an API. Sounds like it offers most of what you need, there's also a [PHP SDK](https://github.com/moltin/php-sdk). You can choose which aspects of the system to use so you should be able to tailor it to your own needs.

Comment: Is that UK only? It doesnt specifically say but pricing is in pounds by default.

Comment: It's based in the UK but multiple [currencies](http://docs.molt.in/#currency_get-currencies) and [taxes](http://docs.molt.in/#tax_get-tax) are supported.