# php shopping cart api

Tags: php, api, cart

i was wondering if there is an API for a shopping cart (PHP). I have looked at solutions like opencart etc, but i have my own design and i just need some kind of API which i can use and add the shopping functionality directly into my website.

I was thinking like 
ExternalCart->createNewProduct(...); or
ExternalCart->showProductInfo(...); or
ExternalCart->addCategory(...)

So the backend is handled by the API and i could just use the output and show it whichever way i want to, hence, not being stuck with the shopping cart's layout or functionality.

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Same this i asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705338/is-there-a-cart-catalog-app-out-there-that-isnt-a-full-site

I didnt get very many answers/suggestions. I decided to just graft OpenCart into that project but im still **extremely interested** if something like this exits.

Comment: yeah i have read you rpost prodigitalson, guess there are not much choices, i heard magento has an api, but requires me to rebuild my php with mcrypt and mdo_mysql, will give it a shot and see if it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railskits has a cool Paypal API (but it's Ruby) -- and doesn't really have cart or order fulfillment.

I've heard ZenMagick has an API wrapping ZenCart, but their demo site seems broken, so that doens't inspire confidence.

Comment: Interesting, but it looks likes a software by itself. Never the less will try and see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your own design - go with a fully JS solution - [Simple Cart](http://simplecartjs.com/) - there is no need for a backend.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="simpleCart.add( 'name=Awesome t-shirt' , 'price=35.95' , 'quantity=1' );">Add To Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to "convert" your site to OpenCart. You can use the its theme system to achieve that. You can read about it here http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=43_44 as its build over MVC architecture and uses CSS, it shouldn't be very hard to adapt. :o)

Answer (score 0):

[Moltin](https://molt.in) might be worth looking into. There is a cart section in their API amongst other ecommerce components. You can use whichever pieces of the ecommerce system that you need. Here's the [documentation](http://docs.molt.in/)